# Compare between Short Time Fourier Transform and Wavelets

Tags: fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples, transformation, signal-processing, wavelets

Fourier transform is localised in only frequency domain but Short time Fourier transform(STFT) is localised both in time and frequency domain same as in wavelets.

I want to know

> How are STFT and Wavelets different in their  working?
>
> Can anybody Compare between Short Time Fourier Transform and Wavelets ?

Comment: This question is too broad and is better answered by the numerous, easy-to-find, and freely available texts on the subject.

Comment: Here is one such resource: http://cnx.org/contents/4a47d3df-bfe5-428c-8bb6-e5b738077caa@2/time-frequency-dictionaries